# AutoToast on each log(cat) message?

Tags: android, logcat, toast

I have an Android app which communicates with an accessory. I need to debug its communications, which means the USB port is already used. I have tried using wireless ADB, but it hasn't been working for me (it'll be working for a few seconds, then flake out a few seconds later and drop the connection,) so I'd like to know if anyone knows of a way to do this:

I'd like to display messages that I send to log in a toast automatically. I'm making the log messages from a class that can't have a context, and thus can't make toasts on its own. I'm hoping there's some easy way I can make it so my main activity just listens for messages to logcat and puts them up in a toast.

Ideas?

Comment: If you can catch log messages, there's an easy way for them to become toasts or notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an interface, make your application implement the interface.

```
public interface Toaster
{
     public void fireToast(String toast);
}



public void fireToast(final String toast)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options.

1. You can view the logs on-device using something like [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat).
2. You can view the logs *after* your debugging session by just plugging the phone in to the USB cable, and then firing up ADB.
3. You can obtain a `Context` from any class in your app by remembering the `Context` on app startup (`Application.onCreate()` is a good place), and providing a static getter for it. From there, it's easy to provide your own logging functionality which sends messages both to the log and to `Toast`s.

Comment: All of these suggestions have the issue that they aren't real time. I can't see when events occur.

Comment: You can with option 3. Just implement your own logging functions which call the logcat functions as well as showing toasts, and get the Context you need from the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static utility method in some class (I pretty much ALWAYS have a Utility class in every project) and put a method in it to use for logging. Don't call Log.X directly, always use your utility method. That utility method would call Log.X (at whatever log level you want), and create a Toast of the same message.